# PHP 7.0 FPM - waiting for available socket chrome

Tags: nginx, debian, php-fpm, php7

I've got a problem with my nginx + php 7.0 FPM.
Chrome is still blocking on " waiting for available socket chrome ".
If i restart php, i'm able to login to my app, and after " waiting for available socket chrome ".
I've checked /var/log/php7.0-fpm.log :

```
[12-Mar-2017 20:48:29] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1088
[12-Mar-2017 20:48:29] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[12-Mar-2017 20:48:29] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[12-Mar-2017 21:15:52] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1121
[12-Mar-2017 21:15:52] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[12-Mar-2017 21:15:52] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[12-Mar-2017 21:16:02] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it
[12-Mar-2017 22:29:25] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it
[13-Mar-2017 09:26:21] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it
[13-Mar-2017 14:58:56] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it
```

I've followed this guide to adjust my values : https://myshell.co.uk/blog/2012/07/adjusting-child-processes-for-php-fpm-nginx/ but i still get the same problem.

I don't know what to do.

Debian 8
PHP 7.0.16-3+0~20170222101552.24+jessie~1.gbpb3eec3 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2017 10:30:30) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.16-3+0~20170222101552.24+jessie~1.gbpb3eec3, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

nginx version: nginx/1.10.3

Comment: You already have your answer here: [13-Mar-2017 14:58:56] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it
Edit the pool in use in /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/ and raise pm_max_children

Comment: @Orphans in my www.conf : pm.max_children = 70
Before it was 5,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23679968/1068283